# nsRouterLink Nativescript from dynamic data from service

Tags: nativescript

i have array from Service

```
private items = new Array<Item>(
        { id: 1, name: "Batman", link: "batmanscreen" },
        { id: 3, name: "doraemon", link: "dorascreen" },
        ...........
```

,

XML Component like :

```
<ActionBar title="Details" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" class="page">
    <FlexboxLayout class="m-15">
        <Label class="h2" [text]="item.id + '. '"></Label>
        <Label class="h2" [text]="item.name"></Label>
    </FlexboxLayout>
    <Label class="h4" [text]="item.link"></Label>
    <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item.link']" text="go TO Screen" ></Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

and the result on android emulator when link got click :

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item.link'
```

i expect become  `nsRouterLink = "['/batmanscreen']"`  , but can not find any guide in nativescript navigation, please guide. 
in angular 2 web i can handle it, but i don`t know how to do it in nativescript..

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the routes like this:

```
private items = new Array<Item>(
        { id: 1, name: "Batman", link: "/batmanscreen" },
        { id: 3, name: "doraemon", link: "/dorascreen" },
```

And do the binding as normally you would in Angular's HTML (when working with {N} + Angular there is not XML):

```
<Label [nsRouterLink]="item.link" text="go TO Screen" ></Label>
```

Comment: thank you for help,it`s answer my question. but before i read your answer, i decided to use code i found in  documentation [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation)  and use `this.routerExtensions.navigate()`

Answer (score 1):

So you're expecting `['/item.link']` to evaluate to `['/batmanscreen']`? That `'/item.link'` is just a string literal so it's not replaced by 'batmanscreen' as you'd hope.

Try like this instead: `['/' + item.link]`.

Comment: it's Nativescript, not javascript and will transform to xml so ['/'+ item.link] wil l result parse error. i tried before

Comment: Trust me, I know what NativeScript is. And I actually verified my suggestion before posting an answer. Just trying to help.

Comment: i think it should  [attributeName ="propertyName".. if i can capture the erorr, i`ll show you the result . i just tried again to make sure even i tried already before